# Is it possible to do a screencast with a webcam inside the screen

Tags: 11.10, webcam, screencast

I was wondering if there is a screencast that can add the webcam to a corner of the screen or if a screencast supports recording the screen with a webcam playing in the background. Like a live webcam inside the screen as seen in several video recordings where the recorder uses his webcam and records the actions in the screen plus him showing himself with a webcam in one of the corners. What I want to ask is which of this is recommended when recording a desktop with a webcam also running:

1. Screencast that supports recording the desktop + the webcam.
2. Start a live feed from the webcam and put it on the desktop. Then record the whole desktop including the webcam in good quality (not jumping frames)
3. Record the desktop and then record the webcam in different times. Then put them together in a video editor like OpenShot.

Anybody with experience with this would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Open Broadcaster Software (OBS)](https://obsproject.com/) it allows you to use multiple sources such as desktop and webcam and position them on the screen while recording:

[image: Open Broadcaster Software streaming with window and webcam input]

Answer (score 2):

gtk-recordmydesktop will record anything that's on screen, including a cheese window diaplaying your webcam, for instance. Nothing special is necessary. You'll probably want to keep the cheese window always on top, though.

Comment: Thanks Jo. Had that in mind, just asking in case some screecast out there has the feature to also add webcam support and make sure it is always on top.

Comment: Though I really would like what you had described Luis